# OrgCharts - Did you write something custom or use shrink-wrapped tool?

Tags: organization, hierarchy, orgchart

I'm just wondering what other developers have done in this area.

What does your organization do to get a hierarchical view of your reporting structure? Did you write something custom or use shrink-wrapped tool? How have you integrated that with other internal tools?

Answer (score 2):

I use [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) for things like this.

Apart from being very fast to construct the charts, it keeps them in a textual form that can be kept under version control or easily compared to previous ones.

With [wiki plugins](http://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Plugins/DirectedGraphPlugin), for wiki engines such as [twiki](http://twiki.org/), you can have the diagrams rendered in the wiki pages.

Answer (score 1):

I use Excel then import that into Visio.

Directors Sectaries’ have to implement so i just ask them to fill in a spreadsheet then import that into Visio - =>.

**UPDATE after comment by SHS =>**

IF you look at the Visio 2007 DATA menu -> Import Data Solution -> Organisation Chart -> there is a wizard (set the columns for the spreadsheet)

All I have in the Columns is

Role - Person - ReportsTo

The wizard helps with the mapping and you get to set who is at the top of the tree.

We have awsome sectaries - but often the least technology driven solution is often the best.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Organizational Chart](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gadgetgallery.html) gadget from the [Google Visualization API](http://www.google.com/ig/directory?url=www.google.com/ig/modules/orgchart.xml).